# Storing xml data inside of bash script

Tags: xml, bash, curl

I have a bash script which curls xml data to a URL. The xml data is currently in a seperate xml file, and everything in that scenarioo works fine. I want to take the contents of the xml file, paste it into the bash script, and pass that data using curl. What I'm asking is, essentially, how do you assign xml data to a variable in bash?

Comment: XML data is just a text string. You assign it just like any other string, with `var='value'`

Comment: @Inian That answer has the XML in a separate file `BuildResult.xml`. He's asking how to do it without a separate file.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but when curling that variable, only part of the first line: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> is being read. Could this be a delimiting issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a here-doc. As mentioned in the `curl` documentation:

> If  you  start the data with the letter `@`, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or `-` if you want curl to read the data from stdin.

```
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/xml" --user u:p -X PUT --data @- "http://..." <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <artifact>
    <a>1.zip</a>
    <b>2-SNAPSHOT.zip</b>
    <c>3-SNAPSHOT.zip</c>
  </artifact>
  <artifact>
    <a>4.tar</a>
    <b>5.tar</b>
    <c>6.tar</c>
  </artifact>
</root>
EOF
```

There here-doc allows you to provide stdin in the script.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but when curling that variable, only part of the first line: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> is being read. Could this be a delimiting issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "curling that variable"? `curl` is for accessing remote files on a web/ftp server, you don't need to use it when the XML is in a variable.

Comment: I am curling with the put method, example: curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --user ****:******** -X PUT --data @HikConfig/NetConfig.xml http://*.*.*.*/ISAPI/System/Network/interfaces

Comment: I've changed the answer to use a here-doc

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed.